# Howto navigate to "anchors" in lists using React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have an app where the user answers a lot of questions. E.g he clicks "I have a car", then I give him some new questions like "which color" and "which brand". The list is dynamic so I never know exactly how far it is from the top to the next question.
Is it possible to do something like `Flatlist.scrollToLocation('#second_question')`?
Well, I know scrollToLocation does not support scroll to id, but does React Native have any other lists that I can use to achieve this?

To me it looks like scrollToLocation requires that one need the exact length. Is there a list in React Native that support "scroll to anchor / id"?